# scanner.nextLine() vs scanner.next() for Mad Libs game

Tags: java

My task is to go through an incomplete mad-lib text file, find all the place holders, given by "< noun/adjective/etc >" and prompt the user to type in an entry to that placeholder, and write the completed mad-lib file to a newly created .txt file.

This code seems to work except it does not accept multi-word input. I have tried `console.nextLine()`, but when I do that, it skips the first place holder for some reason. Would really appreciate some help!

```
public static void create() throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Input file name: ");
    File inputFile = new File(console.next());
    while (!inputFile.canRead()) {

        System.out.print("File not found. Try Again: ");
        inputFile = new File(console.next());
    }
    Scanner inputFileContents = new Scanner(inputFile);

    System.out.print("Output file name: ");
    File outputFile = new File(console.next());
    PrintStream outputFileContents = new PrintStream(outputFile);

    while (inputFileContents.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = inputFileContents.nextLine();
        Scanner linescan = new Scanner(line);
        while (linescan.hasNext()) {
            String word = linescan.next();
            if (word.startsWith("<") && word.endsWith(">") && word.length() > 2) {
                char vow = word.charAt(1);
                String aan = "a";
                if (word.contains("-")) {
                    word = word.replace('-', ' ');
                }
                if (vow == 'a' || vow == 'e' || vow == 'i' || vow == 'o' || vow == 'u') {
                    aan = "an";
                }

                System.out.print("Please type " + aan + " " + word.substring(1, word.length() - 1) + " :");
                outputFileContents.print(console.next());
            } else {
                outputFileContents.print(word);
            }

            outputFileContents.print(" ");
        }
        outputFileContents.println();

    }
```

Comment: What type are the variables `inputFileContents`, `outputFileContents` and `console` in this example?

Comment: inputFileContents is a scanner of the original mad lib file, outputFileContents is a PrintStream for the newly created mad-lib and console is just a regular Scanner for user input.

Comment: I think you should [edit] your question and post a [mcve].